# AWK - How can I get the values that it equal among them? if ... $1== $1?

Tags: awk, escaping, variable-expansion

I am working with a list of DNA sequences. I would like to get all the sequences with the same name ($1). I was thinking to use `if ($1 == "$1")`. But this does not work.

#### result_file:

```
name1 number1 number2 sequenceofname1
name1 number3 number4 sequenceofname1
```

#### script:

```
awk '{if ($1 == "$1") printf("%s_%s_%s \t%s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4);}' <result_file >file.txt
```

How do I pass `$1` to my awk command?

Comment: `$1==$1` will *always* be true as it is an identity. You need to store the value of `$1` you want to match and compare that against each line's `$1` value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use -v option

```
awk -v name="name1" '{
  if ($1 == name) printf("%s_%s_%s \t%s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4);
}' result_file > file.txt
```

or, if this statement in a script

```
awk -v name="$1" '{
  if ($1 == name) printf("%s_%s_%s \t%s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4);
}' result_file > file.txt
```

*-v var=val, Assign the value val to the variable var, before execution of the program begins.  Such variable values are available to the BEGIN block of an AWK program.*

Comment: 1)  `-v name="$1"`  is better. 2). useless cat

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood correctly, you want to use `$1` from your shell script as an argument to the `awk` command within it.

In which case, you want to not quote the `$1` that you want expanding, but do quote the rest of the `awk` command.  One possibility is to double-quote the command:

```
awk "{if (\$1 == \"$1\") printf(\"%s_%s_%s \\t%s\\n\", \$1,\$2,\$3,\$4);}"
```

It can get hard to manage all the backslashes, so you probably prefer to single-quote most of the command, but double-quote the part to be expanded:

```
awk '{if ($1 == "'"$1"'") printf("%s_%s_%s \t%s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4);}'
```

That's slightly tricky to read - the critical bit divides as `'...($1 == "'` `"$1"` `'")...'`.  So there's a double-quote that's part of the Awk command, and one that's for the shell, to keep `$1` in one piece.

Oh, and no need to invoke `cat` - just provide the file as input:

```
awk ...  <result_file >file.txt
```